# Submit button reacts with other buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing some kind of a blog, and I want to be able to click on a button, without the submit button reacts.

```
<form action="" method="Post">
<button onClick="knapp(lank)">Link</button>

<textarea id='knappar'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add post">
</form>


<script>
function knapp(value){
document.getElementById('knappar').value += "LOL";
}
</script>
```

For some reason, whenever I click on the link button, the submit button reacts and submits.

EDIT: the code doesnt work, as it wont print out, but it still refreshes.

Comment: you need to prevent default form button action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a button is within a form and doesn't have a type attribute, it will default to `submit` and therefore submit the form. Add type of `button`:

```
<button type="button" onClick="knapp(lank)">Link</button>
```

This will mean that it won't act as a submit button.